# Why does this random value have a 25/75 distribution instead of 50/50?

Tags: java, random, double, bit-manipulation, probability

**Edit:** So basically what I'm trying to write is a 1 bit hash for `double`.

I want to map a `double` to `true` or `false` with a 50/50 chance. For that I wrote code that picks some random numbers *(just as an example, I want to use this on data with regularities and still get a 50/50 result)*, checks their last bit and increments `y` if it is 1, or `n` if it is 0.

However, this code constantly results in 25% `y` and 75% `n`. Why is it not 50/50? And why such a weird, but straight-forward (1/3) distribution?

```
public class DoubleToBoolean {
    @Test
    public void test() {

        int y = 0;
        int n = 0;
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            double randomValue = r.nextDouble();
            long lastBit = Double.doubleToLongBits(randomValue) & 1;
            if (lastBit == 1) {
                y++;
            } else {
                n++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(y + " " + n);
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
250167 749833
```

Comment: I'm really hoping the answer is something fascinating about random generation of floating-point variates, rather than "LCG has low entropy in the low bits".

Comment: I am very curious, what is the purpose of a "1 bit hash for double"? I seriously can't think of any legitimate application of such a requirement.

Comment: @corsiKa In geometry computations there are often two cases we're looking for to choose from two possible answers (e.g. is point to the left or to the right of the line?), and sometimes it introduces the third, degenerate case (point is right on the line), but you only have two available answers, so you have to pseudorandomly choose one of the available answers in that case. The best way I could think of is to take a 1 bit hash of one of the given double values (remember, those are geometry computations, so there are doubles all over the place).

Comment: @corsiKa (comment divided into two because it is too long) We could start at something simpler like `doubleValue % 1 > 0.5`, but that would be too coarse-grained since it can introduce visible regularities in some cases (all the values are within range of length 1). If that's too coarse-grained, then should we probably try smaller ranges, like `doubleValue % 1e-10 > 0.5e-10`? Well, yes. And taking just the last bit as a hash of a `double` is what happens when you follow this approach till the end, with the least possible modulo.

Comment: So if I understand @Harold's answer correctly, you could get the uniform hash that you want by simply changing the end of line 10 from `& 1;` to `& 3;`, correct?

Comment: @kmote: No, it wouldn't. As [suggested by rici](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/43705716) and [proven by harold](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/43705764), you'd have to multiply the number by 2^53 and then check whether the result is an even number.

Comment: @kmote then you'd still have the heavily biased least significant bit, and the other bit doesn't compensate for it - in fact it is also biased towards zero (but less so), for exactly the same reason. So the distribution would be about 50, 12.5, 25, 12.5. `(lastbit & 3) == 0` would work though, odd as it is.

Comment: @harold: my bad. I actually meant to say `& 2;` (or any other power of 2). Couldn't we expect all of the other bits (besides the final biased one) to be uniformly distributed?

Comment: @kmote no because the same effect applies to them - if you roll lower than a certain number for the 53bit random `long`, then that bit will be guaranteed 0 (and otherwise 50/50). So they're zero with probability 75%, 62.5%, 56.25%, 53.125% etc

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Because nextDouble works like this: ([source](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Random-source.html))

```
public double nextDouble()
{
    return (((long) next(26) << 27) + next(27)) / (double) (1L << 53);
}
```

`next(x)` makes `x` random bits.

Now why does this matter? Because about half the numbers generated by the first part (before the division) are less than `1L << 52`, and therefore their significand doesn't entirely fill the 53 bits that it could fill, meaning the least significant bit of the significand is always zero for those.

---

Because of the amount of attention this is receiving, here's some extra explanation of what a `double` in Java (and many other languages) really looks like and why it mattered in this question.

Basically, a `double` looks like this: ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:IEEE_754_Double_Floating_Point_Format.svg))

[image: double layout]

A very important detail not visible in this picture is that numbers are "normalized"<sup>1</sup> such that the 53 bit fraction starts with a 1 (by choosing the exponent such that it is so), that 1 is then omitted. That is why the picture shows 52 bits for the fraction (significand) but there are effectively 53 bits in it.

The normalization means that if in the code for `nextDouble` the 53rd bit is set, that bit is the implicit leading 1 and it goes away, and the other 52 bits are copied literally to the significand of the resulting `double`. If that bit is not set however, the remaining bits must be shifted left until it becomes set.

On average, half the generated numbers fall into the case where the significand was *not* shifted left at all (and about half those have a 0 as their least significant bit), and the other half is shifted by at least 1 (or is just completely zero) so their least significant bit is always 0.

1: not always, clearly it cannot be done for zero, which has no highest 1. These numbers are called denormal or subnormal numbers, see [wikipedia:denormal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number).

Comment: Hooray! Just what I was hoping for.

Comment: This is very cool. Just curious, how did you come by this knowledge? And would you happen to know why this is the best way to generate random doubles? Again, very cool +1

Comment: @Matt Presumably it's a speed optimization. The alternative would be to generate the exponent with a geometric distribution, and then the mantissa separately.

Comment: Just where on earth do you learn all this : ( Totally off-topic but if you can share books where I can learn about this kind of specific, almost "trivia" topics, I'd appreciate any reference!

Comment: @Matt: Define "best." `random.nextDouble()` is typically the "best" way for what it's intended for, but most people are not trying to produce a 1-bit hash from their random double. Are you looking for uniform distribution, resistance to cryptanalysis, or what?

Comment: @Sneftel Yeah, I guess that makes sense when I think about it. I just wouldn't have gotten there quickly without seeing the answer first. Thanks!

Comment: This answer suggests that if OP had multiplied the random number by 2^53 and checked whether the resulting integer was odd, there would have been a 50/50 distribution.

Comment: @harold, yeah. I guess OP didn't ask "...and how do I fix it", but I can't help thinking that it would be a useful addition for anyone else with a similar need.

Comment: Great answer! Sort of off-topic, is there a reason the first part of the division is not just `next(53)`?  I'm guessing `next(x)` only works with values up to 48 or something, by glancing at the source, but that is not specified in the doc.

Comment: @The111 it says [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#next(int)) that `next` must return an `int`, so it can only have up to 32 bits anyway

Comment: "What a `double` looks like in Java (and many other languages)": it's actually what a 64-bit float looks like in most processors these days.  It's not really a "language" thing.

Comment: @ajb it *is* a language thing. Languages could easily specify a completely different format. That would be really inconvenient, but they totally could. What the processor supports doesn't matter to what you see happening at the language level. Some languages merely *allow* this format, and then it's an implementation thing (but still not a processor thing!)

Answer (score 48):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble()):

> The method nextDouble is implemented by class Random as if by:
>
> ```
> public double nextDouble() {
>   return (((long)next(26) << 27) + next(27))
>       / (double)(1L << 53);
> }
> ```

But it also states the following (emphasis mine):

> [In early versions of Java, the result was incorrectly calculated as:
>
> ```
>  return (((long)next(27) << 27) + next(27))
>      / (double)(1L << 54);
> ```
>
> This might seem to be equivalent, if not better, but in fact it introduced a large nonuniformity because of the bias in the rounding of floating-point numbers: **it was three times as likely that the low-order bit of the significand would be 0 than that it would be 1**! This nonuniformity probably doesn't matter much in practice, but we strive for perfection.]

This note has been there since Java 5 at least (docs for Java <= 1.4 are behind a loginwall, too lazy to check). This is interesting, because the problem apparently still exists even in Java 8. Perhaps the "fixed" version was never tested?

Comment: Strange. I just reproduced this on Java 8.

Comment: I'm using Java 8 as well.

Comment: Now that's interesting, because I just argued that the bias still applies to the new method. Am I wrong?

Comment: @harold: No, I think you're right and whoever tried to fix this bias might have made a mistake.

Comment: @harold Time to send an email to the Java guys.

Comment: "Perhaps the fixed version was never tested?"  Actually, on rereading this, I think the doc was about a different problem.  Note that it mentions **rounding**, which suggests that they didn't consider the "three times as likely" to be the problem, directly, but rather that this leads to a non-uniform distribution when the values are _rounded_.  Note that in my answer, the values I list are uniformly distributed, but the low-order bit as represented in IEEE format are not uniform.  I think the problem they fixed had to do with the overall uniformity, not the uniformity of the low bit.

Comment: In other words, the purpose of the fix was never to straighten out the distribution of the low-order bit.  That would not have been a worthwhile goal, in my opinion.

Answer (score 33):

This result doesn't surprise me given how floating-point numbers are represented.  Let's suppose we had a very short floating-point type with only 4 bits of precision.  If we were to generate a random number between 0 and 1, distributed uniformly, there would be 16 possible values:

```
0.0000
0.0001
0.0010
0.0011
0.0100
...
0.1110
0.1111
```

If that's how they looked in the machine, you could test the low-order bit to get a 50/50 distribution.  However, IEEE floats are represented as a power of 2 times a mantissa; one field in the float is the power of 2 (plus a fixed offset).  The power of 2 is selected so that the "mantissa" part is always a number >= 1.0 and < 2.0.  This means that, in effect, the numbers other than `0.0000` would be represented like this:

```
0.0001 = 2^(-4) x 1.000
0.0010 = 2^(-3) x 1.000
0.0011 = 2^(-3) x 1.100
0.0100 = 2^(-2) x 1.000
... 
0.0111 = 2^(-2) x 1.110
0.1000 = 2^(-1) x 1.000
0.1001 = 2^(-1) x 1.001
...
0.1110 = 2^(-1) x 1.110
0.1111 = 2^(-1) x 1.111
```

(The `1` before the binary point is an implied value; for 32- and 64-bit floats, no bit is actually allocated to hold this `1`.)

But looking at the above should demonstrate why, if you convert the representation to bits and look at the low bit, you will get zero 75% of the time.  This is due to all values less than 0.5 (binary `0.1000`), which is half the possible values, having their mantissas shifted over, causing 0 to appear in the low bit.  The situation is essentially the same when the mantissa has 52 bits (not including the implied 1) as a `double` does.

(Actually, as @sneftel suggested in a comment, we *could* include more than 16 possible values in the distribution, by generating:

```
0.0001000 with probability 1/128
0.0001001 with probability 1/128
...
0.0001111 with probability 1/128
0.001000  with probability 1/64
0.001001  with probability 1/64
...
0.01111   with probability 1/32 
0.1000    with probability 1/16
0.1001    with probability 1/16
...
0.1110    with probability 1/16
0.1111    with probability 1/16
```

But I'm not sure it's the kind of distribution most programmers would expect, so it probably isn't worthwhile.  Plus it doesn't gain you much when the values are used to generate integers, as random floating-point values often are.)

Comment: Using floating point to get random bits/bytes/anything makes me shudder anyway. Even for random distributions between 0 and n, we have [better alternatives (look at arc4random_uniform)](https://www.mirbsd.org/man3/arc4random_uniform) than random*n…